# MongoDB returning a lot of data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to grab all documents from my "chats" collection. When I loop through my results variable and console log item, I get a lot of data back. how can I query all objects and get just the document fields?

```
//create route 
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    db.connect(url, function(err, db){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("Connected");
        }

        getAllChats(db, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

    });

    res.render('index.jade');
});

var getAllChats = function(db, callback){

    var collection = db.collection('chats');
    var results = collection.find();

    results.each(function(err, item) {
        // If the item is null then the cursor is exhausted/empty and closed
        console.log(item);
        if(item == null) {
            db.close(); // you may not want to close the DB if you have more code....
            return;
        }
        // otherwise, do something with the item
    });
    callback(results);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get just the document fields"? Can you provide an example of the data being returned that you want excluded?

Comment: what is your console? and which fields do you want  please elaborate it more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a projection to achieve this.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

```
var collection = db.collection('chats');
var results = collection.find(query, projection);
```

In your case query will be `{}`;
Projection will be `{FieldYouNeed: 1, fieldYouNeed: 1, ...}`;

Here is example

```
var results = collection.find({name: "developer"}, {_id: 0, name: 1, email:1});
```

In this case only `name` and `email` will be returned from DB.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even when I pass an empty object for the query and specify what fields I need with a value of 1, I still get a huge object back. I can see the results at the bottom of the returned object.

Comment: The extra data was coming from my console log in my route. I was console logging the callback so it was printing the results object.